# Edit each row of a column in a huge dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, char, row

I have a dataframe with some columns
The first column is called TIME...in the first row of that column the time is `2022-06-01T00:00:00.0/2022-06-01T00:01:00.0`
in the second row, the time is `2022-06-01T00:01:00.0/2022-06-01T00:02:00.0`
I want to cut whatever exists in each row of THAT COLUMN  after the /

```
for row in DATA['TIME']:
    for char in row:
        while char != "/" :
           continue
        else :
           break
print (column)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) :

```
DATA["TIME"] = DATA["TIME"].str.split("/", expand=True)[0]
```

Or [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) :

```
DATA["TIME"] = DATA["TIME"].str.extract("(.+)/", expand=False)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(DATA)
                    TIME
0  2022-06-01T00:00:00.0
1  2022-06-01T00:01:00.0
```